# SharePoint power automate, HTTP trigger free alternative?

Tags: flow, webhooks

[image]

Is there a free alternative of Send HTTP action in Power Automate? Need to call small C# function from Power Automate, don't need to read response from it. Maybe someone realized something similar?
Do [Webhooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/webhooks/get-started-webhooks) need any licenses?

Want to do something like here (run small function that decodes image and puts it to SP library), but for free
https://poszytek.eu/en/microsoft-en/office-365-en/powerautomate-en/how-to-move-copy-infopath-attachments-in-sharepoint-online/

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. You could create your own custom connector but that also [requires a Power Automate licence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/powerapps-flow-licensing-faq#what-are-microsoft-power-apps-and-power-automate-use-rights-for-microsoft-365-applications).

As for SharePoint webhooks, your Power Automate flow could create/edit an item in a SharePoint list which could then trigger a webhook to call your API. This isn't a great solution, but wouldn't require a premium Power Automate licence.

Worth noting, if the flow only runs under the context of your user, then you only need one premium licence.

Comment: Thank You much @Callum Crowley!

>> an item in a SharePoint list which could then trigger a webhook to call your API

Do I understand right that SharePoint webhooks don't need additional fees?
So if I use a web-service stored on my server, triggered by webhook - this approach doesn't need premium, does it?.. Best regards, Gennady

Comment: They don't, the webhooks are within your basic SharePoint Online offering. Though honestly, I would probably opt for a Power Automate licence for whatever user account is going to be running the flow.

Comment: Thank You much Callum! I'll try to understand what fees there should be (for Premium HTTP connector + Azure function ‍♂️..). Best regards, Gennady